# CSS assets simply stopped to reflect any change

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I don't know, I can't remember that I've changed something in config file, but I just faced this - Rails doesn't respond to any CSS changes.

I even just removed all CSS for one controller - nothing changed (so no just typo with some class or id).

What can possible cause this?

Comment: Oh, sorry guys, it is completely non-code issue, I just renamed app, but text-editor (RubyMine) continiued to start server from folder with previous name, just another version of project. Should I delete question?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command:

```
$ rake tmp:clear tmp:create assets:clean
```

This will clear your temporary files & cached asset files.