# Why does rails remember deleted css?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, git

For some reason, unknown to me, I am forced to precompile my assets when I deploy to Heroku.  After I locally precompile and deploy, I obviously go back to changing my site.  I have come across a problem where Rails "remembers" css rules that I have precompiled when I try to change them in my app/assets folder.  I thought this might be because there is a new assets folder in public/assets and these styles might take precedence.  I removed this folder and the problem still persisted.  I can add css styles but I can not delete/overide css styles that had been previously precompiled.  I searched these forums further and found [CSS assets simply stopped to reflect any change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16654517/css-assets-simply-stopped-to-reflect-any-change).  I tried it.  However it has not fixed the problem.  The only time I can get my css changes to apply is after I first change the style in my app/assets folder, then I precompile my assets locally, then only after I push to git AND deploy to Heroku will my changes reflect locally.

I would post code but I'm not sure what code would be relevant.  Since what I'm talking about is a simple "border: 1px solid black;" style.

I think it is worth mentioning that after I deploy to heroku everything always works as intended.

Thank you for any help you might be able to give me.

Comment: Why do you precompile your assets locally?

Comment: Normalize your css, aka reset.

Comment: @Marek Lipka, Some weeks ago I came across an error uploading to Heroku where the normal "git push heroku" without precompiling assets no longer worked for me.  After reading these forums someone suggested to precompile my assets so Heroku didn't have to.  It worked and I just stuck with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clean out your assets before you precompile anew:

```
rake assets:clean
```

otherwise your local machine may use the existing precompiled assets, rather than the new (changed) assets.